# Run first program with Gecode

Tags: c++, constraints, windows-8.1, gecode

Please i need your help.

I have installed the toolkit for developing constraint-based systems and applications **Gecode 4.4.0** on Windows 8, also the compilator C++ **Dev C++ 5.9.2** but i still don't know how can i run my first program or the example provided by the insallation.

I've read that i need a make file but really i have not yet succeeded compilation or execution.

Compile command :

> g++.exe -D__DEBUG__ main.o sat.o -o TestGecode.exe -L"C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib32" -L"C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib32" -static-libgcc
>   -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Gecode/include" -m32 -g3

Output error :

> sat.o: In function `ZN6Gecode9ExceptionD2Ev': c:/program files
>   (x86)/dev-cpp/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/gecode/support/exception.hpp:46:
>   undefined reference to`_imp___ZTVN6Gecode9ExceptionE' sat.o: In
>   function `ZN6Gecode15MemoryExhaustedC1Ev': c:/program files
>   (x86)/dev-cpp/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/gecode/support/exception.hpp:90:
>   undefined reference to`_imp___ZN6Gecode9ExceptionC2EPKcS2_' sat.o: In
>   function `ZNK6Gecode9PosChoice7archiveERNS_7ArchiveE': ...

Comment: Looks a lot like you haven't pointed your development tool at the Gecode libraries. Not sure how you do this with DevC++, but it should be well documented. Try plopping "dev c++ add library to project" into your web search o' choice and see what comes back.

Comment: it already pointed on the Gecode libraries.

Answer (score 0):

> -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Gecode/include"

Provides the path to the Gecode headers, not the path to the libraries, to g++ as a library path. Consider using

> -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Gecode/lib"

instead.

`-L` only points the linker at where to find the libraries. It doesn't tell the linker what libraries to use. `-l <name of library>` is also required on the command line. The Gecode documentation should tell you which libraries to link in order to get the functions you need. A quick read suggests GecodeSupport contains `Gecode::Exception`. Unfortunately it doesn't come right out and say it on the `Gecode::Exception` doc page. You should need to add `-lGecodeSupport<version number>` to the command line.

Caveat: If you installed any of the pre-packaged versions for Windows provided on the Gecode site, they all look to be for Visual Studio and won't be recognizable to GCC. If you downloaded and built Gecode from source, you should be good to go.

Comment: Actually, i'am using : CodeBlock and Dev C++ .

Comment: DevC++ is a IDE wrapping mingw's port of GCC. Note the compile command starting with g++, GCC's C++ compiler. GCC's linker will not be able to understand the file format used by Visual Studio's libraries.

Comment: I installed Visual Studio 2012, and I have compiled. But now I have another error, i can not run the program, because an error occurs during the execution and the program does not end !!  1 - `cl /DNDEBUG /EHsc /MD /Ox /wd4355 -I"E:/prg files/gecode/x86/include" -c -Fo"C:/Users/sb/Desktop/money.obj" -Tp"C:/Users/sb/Desktop/money.cpp" `  2 -  
`cl /DNDEBUG /EHsc /MD /Ox /wd4355 -I"E:/prg files/gecode/x86/include"    -Fe"C:/Users/sb/Desktop/money.exe" "C:/Users/sb/Desktop/money.obj" /link /LIBPATH:" E:/prg files/gecode/x86/lib"`

  3 - `C:/Users/sb/Desktop/money.exe`

Comment: Visual studio has a top-notch debugger. Run the program in the debugger for a minute or two, then pause the program and see where it got stuck.